# Alternative(?) Java solution | ArrayList

Tags: java

I am writing a Java code that should remove all the "0" in an arraylist and return a new list, identical, but without the "0".

For an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] sound = {0, 0 , 0, 0, -14, 120, 67, -234, -15, -389, 289, 178, -437, 33, 15, 0, 0, -32, 230, 368};
    int[] result = trimSilenceFromFront(sound);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

Should be:

```
[-14, 120, 67, -234, -15, -389, 289, 178, -437, 33, 15, 0, 0, -32, 230, 368]
```

I did this code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NoZero {
    public static int[] trimSilenceFromFront(int[] samples) {
        int[] newArrayList = new int[samples.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; i = i + 1) {
            if (samples[i] != 0) {
                newArrayList.add(samples);
            }
        }
        return newArrayList;   
    }
}
```

When I looked at the answer they had while loops mixed with for loops. But since there is more than one way to solve this: is my code wrong?

Update: I misunderstood the question. I thought it should remove all the "0". But as you can see on the result it should only remove the silence at the start.

Thank you all!

Comment: There are 10000 ways to do that. How does the number of solutions related to the correctness of your code?

Comment: `int[] newArrayList = new int[samples.length];` This creates a new _array_ not an `ArrayList`. Also `newArrayList.add(samples);` this would try to add the entire `samples` array to `newArrayList`, not just the value at `samples[i]`

Comment: `newArrayList` is `int[]`, you cannot use `add` on it. It's *not* an array list.

Comment: Yes, you code is wrong. Arrays don't have methods `newArrayList.add(samples)`.

Comment: Are you sure about your result? You claim that it shouldn't contain `0` but I see few of them in your result.

Comment: According to the function name, only the leading zeroes should be removed.

Comment: Yes, your solution is wrong. You give a lot of conflicting information. At first you say you want to remove all zeros from an array. Then you give an example showing that you want to remove leading zeros only. This is in line with the name of your method (which I assume was given to you for this exercise). Your implementation removes all zeros again, however, in line with your first description.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find the first non-zero value and take a copy from that index to the end. There are many ways to do this, e.g.:

```
public static int[] trimSilenceFromFront(int[] samples) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i++ < samples.length) {
        if (samples[i] != 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(samples, i, samples.length);
}
```

Comment: This is the most effective way to do it (performance wise)

Answer (score 0):

There are unlimited ways to solve a problem with Java. Viability of a single solution can be measured in different ways.

I find the biggest measurements to be code readability, maintainability, memory usage and execution speed. Consider your requirements and try to balance these measurements in your favor.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @Bubletan is by far the more efficient one.

If you want another solution you can also make it works with LinkedList :

```
private static Integer[] trimSilenceFromFront(Integer[] samples) {
    LinkedList<Integer> soundList = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(samples));
    boolean soundStarted = false;
    while(!soundStarted && soundList.size()>0){
        if(soundList.peekFirst()!=null && soundList.peekFirst()==0){
            soundList.removeFirst();
        }
        else {
            soundStarted=true;
        }
    }
    return soundList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Nevermind, this trims all Silence from range, not just from the front. Sorry about that, your question and code contradicted one another.

---

This is a messy solution I guess, but might lead you down the right path

```
        int[] sound = {0, 0 , 0, 0, -14, 120, 67, -234, -15, -389, 289, 178, -437, 33, 15, 0, 0, -32, 230, 368};

        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i = 0; i < sound.length; i++) {
            if(sound[i] != 0) {
                temp.add(sound[i]);
            }
        }

        int[] trimmedSound = new int[temp.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
            trimmedSound[i] = temp.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sound));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(trimmedSound));
    }
```

this is the output

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, -14, 120, 67, -234, -15, -389, 289, 178, -437, 33, 15, 0, 0, -32, 230, 368]
[-14, 120, 67, -234, -15, -389, 289, 178, -437, 33, 15, -32, 230, 368]
```